# Cosa vuol dire "accuaiarsi"?

Tags: word-meaning, verbs, regional

Nel romanzo *Vita* di Melania G. Mazzucco ho letto:

> La processione la trascina nella direzione opposta, e le impedisce di precipitarsi a Prince Street, affidarsi alla corda scivolosa e controllare se c’è ancora sulla porta della sua vecchia casa il corno contro il malocchio. Ma il passato ritorna quando la luna sarà sempre piena, quando il mare **s’accuaierà** come uno specchio e i gatti cominceranno a parlare, e voltarsi indietro non serve a niente.

Sapreste spiegarmi il significato di "accuaiarsi" in questo brano? Immagino si tratti di un termine di origine dialettale, possibilmente correlato al napoletano. Non ho trovato "accuaiare" né "accuaiarsi" su nessun dizionario italiano. Ho cercato questi verbi e anche "accuaià" sul [vocabolario napoletano-italiano di Giuseppe Giacco e sul *Lessico e Letteratura del Dialetto Napoletano* di Salvatore Argenziano e Gianna De Filippis](https://italian.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1397), ma non li ho trovati.

Comment: Penso che si intenda accuietà, cioè calmarsi.

Comment: Potrebbe essere l'ennesima derivazione da uno slang italoamericano per esempio da "quiet" ? ;)

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi: Appare nel testo d'una [canzone](http://nazzarenocolangelo.altervista.org/alterpages/files/Icantidellatradizioneaviglianese2.pdf) che non sembra avere niente a che vedere con l'inglese.